# Check if function is in C or Lua implemented

Tags: c, function, types, lua

I've created a table and assigned a method with `lua_pushcfunction` named `mytable:myfunction()`. In a different (callback) context it's necessarily that `myfunction` will be overriden inside the Lua script. For some reasons, if i call `myfunction` from the C host, I need to know, if `myfunction` is still the c function or was replaced by the script.

Is there a way to test (from C), if the C method is still attached or is replaced by some Lua code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use [**`lua_iscfunction`**](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_iscfunction).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use [**`lua_tocfunction`**](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_tocfunction). This allows you to also check if the C function you got back is the one you expect.